# Does Genesis 22:17 phrase "greatly multiply your seed" contradict Galatians 3:16 which emphasizes "his seed" as in "one" (Jesus Christ))?

Tags: galatians, pauline-epistles

How can Genesis 22:17 says "greatly multiply your seed" relate with Galatians 3:16 states "his seed" as in "one" (Jesus Christ))?

It seems to me that Genesis 22:17-18 uses seed to represent the Israelites people.

> Genesis 22:17-18 New American Standard Bible (NASB)
>
> 17 indeed I will
>   greatly bless you, and I will **greatly multiply your seed as the stars
>   of the heavens and as the sand which is on the seashore**; and your
>   seed shall possess the gate of their enemies. 18 In your seed all the
>   nations of the earth shall be blessed, because you have obeyed My
>   voice.”
>
> Galatians 3:16 New American Standard Bible (NASB)
>
> 16 Now the promises were spoken to Abraham and to **his seed.** He does
>   not say, “And to seeds,” as referring to many, but **rather to one**, “And
>   to your seed,” that is, Christ.

Therefore, Does Genesis 22:17 says "greatly multiply your seed" contradict Galatians 3:16 states "his seed" as in "one" (Jesus Christ))?

Answer (score 3):

Verse 17 is made with the descendants of Abraham through Isaac and Jakob:

> Genesis 22:17 New American Standard Bible (NASB)
>
> 17 indeed I will greatly bless you, and I will greatly multiply your
>   seed as the stars of the heavens and as the sand which is on the
>   seashore; and your seed shall possess the gate of their enemies.

Verse 18 is about his one descendant, Jesus:

> Genesis 22:18 New American Standard Bible (NASB)
>
> 18 In your seed all the nations of the earth shall be blessed, because
>   you have obeyed My voice.”

So no, no contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

“God gave the promises to Abraham and his child... the Scripture doesn’t say “to his children” as if it meant many descendants.  Rather, it says “to his child” – and that, of course, means Christ” (Galatians 3:16 NIV).  Here is the NIV Study Bible explanation:

> “Seed” can refer to a single descendant or to many descendants (Genesis 12:7; 13:15).  Although the promise has a plural sense, this singular noun points to the one descendant, Christ who completely fulfilled the promise.  The heirs of the promise are not Jacob’s physical children, but the spiritual children of Christ by the Spirit through faith.

There is no contradiction between the promise given to Abraham in Genesis 22:17 that God would multiply his seed through Isaac, and Christ Jesus being the ultimate seed of Abraham, since Jesus’ genealogy can be traced through his mother, Mary, back fourteen generations to Abraham, Isaac, Jacob and Judah (Matthew 1:1-17).

In Genesis 22:17-18 the word “descendants” literally means “seed.”  The natural descendants of Abraham are indeed blessed by God through his promise, and because Christ Jesus was born as a descendant of Abraham “all the nations of the earth will be blessed” (Genesis 22:18).